# What android icon app is this?pls help

Tags: applications, android-versions

[image]

Please help me identify the icon encircled in my attached photo..thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it has something to do with you messenger app. Long press it and choose info. If it gives you an option to uninstall, it's a user app, uninstall it. If it doesn't, it's a system app. Force stop, and see if your messenger still works. Myself, I'd just uninstall the app if it's causing problems. If not, hide it.